# Uncountable model testing with rspec and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using rails 5.0.0.1 to build a small inventory type system for some equipment I lone to people.  One of my models is named equipment which of course is an uncountable model (singular and plural of equipment is the same).  When I try to write feature tests for this model I get one of two possible errors when I try to visit the index page.  If I use "visit equipment_url" I am told there is no route for "show" because there is no id.  This is a correct error if I wanted to go to show but I don't.  If I try "visit equipment_index_url" I am told there is no method visit.

```
Routes
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
                  root GET    /                                       inventory#index
      delete_equipment GET    /equipment/:id/delete(.:format)         equipment#delete
                       DELETE /equipment/:id/delete(.:format)         equipment#destroy
       equipment_index GET    /equipment(.:format)                    equipment#index
                       POST   /equipment(.:format)                    equipment#create
         new_equipment GET    /equipment/new(.:format)                equipment#new
        edit_equipment GET    /equipment/:id/edit(.:format)           equipment#edit
             equipment GET    /equipment/:id(.:format)                equipment#show
                       PATCH  /equipment/:id(.:format)                equipment#update
                       PUT    /equipment/:id(.:format)                equipment#update
                       DELETE /equipment/:id(.:format)                equipment#destroy
      delete_specialty GET    /specialties/:id/delete(.:format)       specialties#delete
                       DELETE /specialties/:id/delete(.:format)       specialties#destroy
           specialties GET    /specialties(.:format)                  specialties#index
                       POST   /specialties(.:format)                  specialties#create
         new_specialty GET    /specialties/new(.:format)              specialties#new
        edit_specialty GET    /specialties/:id/edit(.:format)         specialties#edit
             specialty GET    /specialties/:id(.:format)              specialties#show
                       PATCH  /specialties/:id(.:format)              specialties#update
                       PUT    /specialties/:id(.:format)              specialties#update
                       DELETE /specialties/:id(.:format)              specialties#destroy
          delete_event GET    /events/:id/delete(.:format)            events#delete
                       DELETE /events/:id/delete(.:format)            events#destroy
                events GET    /events(.:format)                       events#index
                       POST   /events(.:format)                       events#create
             new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                   events#new
            edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)              events#edit
                 event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                   events#show
                       PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                   events#update
                       PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                   events#update
                       DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                   events#destroy
           delete_type GET    /types/:id/delete(.:format)             types#delete
                       DELETE /types/:id/delete(.:format)             types#destroy
                 types GET    /types(.:format)                        types#index
                       POST   /types(.:format)                        types#create
              new_type GET    /types/new(.:format)                    types#new
             edit_type GET    /types/:id/edit(.:format)               types#edit
                  type GET    /types/:id(.:format)                    types#show
                       PATCH  /types/:id(.:format)                    types#update
                       PUT    /types/:id(.:format)                    types#update
                       DELETE /types/:id(.:format)                    types#destroy
delete_event_specialty GET    /event_specialties/:id/delete(.:format) event_specialties#delete
                       DELETE /event_specialties/:id/delete(.:format) event_specialties#destroy
     event_specialties GET    /event_specialties(.:format)            event_specialties#index
                       POST   /event_specialties(.:format)            event_specialties#create
   new_event_specialty GET    /event_specialties/new(.:format)        event_specialties#new
  edit_event_specialty GET    /event_specialties/:id/edit(.:format)   event_specialties#edit
       event_specialty GET    /event_specialties/:id(.:format)        event_specialties#show
                       PATCH  /event_specialties/:id(.:format)        event_specialties#update
                       PUT    /event_specialties/:id(.:format)        event_specialties#update
                       DELETE /event_specialties/:id(.:format)        event_specialties#destroy
```

spec/features/equipment_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Equipment", type: :request do
  describe "GET /equipment" do
    it "Adds a new equipment" do
        @types = FactoryGirl.create_list(:multitype, 25)
        @specialties = FactoryGirl.create_list(:multispecialty, 25)
        visit equipment_index_url
        expect{
            click_link 'New Equipment'
            fill_in "Equipment No", with: "2"
            fill_in "Serial", with: "123456"
            fill_in "Description", with: "Test Equipment"
            select "radio10", from: "equipment_type_id"
            select "tech13", from: "equipment_specialty_id"
            click_button "Create Equipment"
        }.to change(Equipment, :count).by(1)
        expect(page).to have_content("Equipment was successfully created")
    end

    it "deletes without javascript" do
        equipment = FactoryGirl.create(:equipment)
        visit equipment_url
        expect {
            click_link "Destroy"
        }.to change(Equipment, :count).by(-1)
        expect(page).to have_content("Equipment was successfully destroyed")
    end

    it "edits a equipment" do
        equipment = FactoryGirl.create(:equipment)
        visit equipment_url
        click_link 'Edit'
        fill_in "Serial", with: "456789"
        click_button "Update Equipment"
        expect(page).to have_content("Equipment was successfully updated")
        expect(page).to have_content("Serial: 456789")
    end

    it "shows a equipment" do
        equipment = FactoryGirl.create(:equipment)
        visit equipment_url
        click_link 'Show'
        expect(page).to have_content("Serial: rad123")
        expect(page).to have_link("Edit")
        expect(page).to have_link("Back", href: equipment_path)
    end
  end
end
```

Errors

```
Equipment
  GET /equipment
    Adds a new equipment (FAILED - 1)
    deletes without javascript (FAILED - 2)
    edits a equipment (FAILED - 3)
    shows a equipment (FAILED - 4)
```

Failures:

1) Equipment GET /equipment Adds a new equipment
     Failure/Error: visit equipment_index_url

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Equipment::GETEquipment:0x000000065c32e8>
 # ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:112:in `block in run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `loop'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
```

2) Equipment GET /equipment deletes without javascript
     Failure/Error: visit equipment_url

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"} missing required keys: [:id]
 # ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:112:in `block in run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `loop'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
```

3) Equipment GET /equipment edits a equipment
     Failure/Error: visit equipment_url

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"} missing required keys: [:id]
 # ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:112:in `block in run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `loop'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
```

4) Equipment GET /equipment shows a equipment
     Failure/Error: visit equipment_url

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"} missing required keys: [:id]
 # ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:112:in `block in run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `loop'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:101:in `run'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
 # /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.2/lib/rspec/retry.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in setup'

Finished in 0.28107 seconds (files took 2.61 seconds to load)
4 examples, 4 failures
```

Failed examples:

```
rspec ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:5 # Equipment GET /equipment Adds a new equipment
rspec ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:21 # Equipment GET /equipment deletes without javascript
rspec ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:30 # Equipment GET /equipment edits a equipment
rspec ./spec/features/equipment_spec.rb:40 # Equipment GET /equipment shows a equipment
```

Any Ideas on how to make it work would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the "RSpec.describe "Equipment", type: :request" has to be type ":feature" for capybara testing to work properly.

This should fix the show errors, because I assume it doesn't have an ID because it is not visiting equipment_url correctly. If that isn't the problem, then equipment#show is not receiving an instance variable.

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  However changing it makes no difference.  What I think is happening is that rspec is choosing the show when it should not.  In the case of uncountable models rails makes the indx route equipment_index so as to differentiate it from the equipment routes used in the show and other singular routes that require an id.  The app works when actually run in a browser but rspec is not correctly folowing the routes.

Comment: I stand corrected.  This did cure the issue when using equipment_index_url.  I did not see it yesterday becuase there is another error and it got pushed off the screen.

Comment: glad I could help!